# how to detect region and use the right decimal place separator with Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use material-UI in my react project and it seems that by default the period "." is always the decimal place separator in number input fields, if I type comma nothing happens. I've changed my linux keyboard input format, region and language hoping that it would be automatically detected but "." remains the decimal place separator. Does anyone know a straightforward way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you mean by fields. But if you mean input fields, then [their documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries) states that you need to use a third-party package for that. The one they reference allows setting a `decimalSeparator`: https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format#props

If you are not talking about input fields, then I recommend using the `toLocaleString()` method of the JS Number type. It will always format the number according to the locale of the user, e.g.:

```js
> 1234567.90.toLocaleString()
'1,234,567.9'
```

---

**Update:**
I'm surprised react-number-format doesn't allow you to set a locale directly. One hack around that would be to set:

```
thousandSeparator = 1234.toLocaleString()[1];
decimalSeparator = 0.1.toLocaleString()[1];
```

Comment: I meant input field. I've already updated my question. react-number-format allows you to set the decimal separator manually, but how can I detect which separator to use depending on the location the user is?

Comment: Yeah, that seems a little poorly supported. I've updated my answer with a hack to get those separators. JS has an i8n API (see the Intl object) that takes care of these things, so it's weird the library doesn't just use that.